# Bit field padding and layout in memory

Tags: c, bit-fields

Let's say I have the following defined `bitfield`:

```
struct font {
    unsigned int bold : 1;
    unsigned int italics : 4;
    unsigned int underline : 1;
};
```

If I create the following new `font` object:

```
struct font myFont = {1,1,1};
```

How would the bit field be stored in memory? For example, like this?

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1
```

Or this?

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1
```

Does endian-ness matter on a bit-field? Or is this compiler-dependent, or how is this determined?

Comment: It's entirely compiler- and/or ABI-dependent.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see, thanks for the answer. Is bit-layout related to endianness, or byte-order and bit-order/padding are two completely separate things?

Comment: Everything that the Standard has to say about bitfield layout is 6.7.2.1 (9-15) and as you can see it's not much; nearly every sentence just says "implementation-defined".

Comment: Endianness has to do with which bytes of a word reside at which addresses.  The whole concept is inapplicable to bits because bits don't have their own addresses.  It's up to the implementation whether bitfields use the least-significant bits first, or most-significant, or how they're packed, and there's no particular reason why this decision needs to have much to do with the endianness of the machine.

Comment: In the x86-64 SysV ABI, for instance, bitfields are specified as "allocated from right to left", meaning they use the least-significant bits first.  (Usually bit 0 is least significant and written on the right, so your diagrams seem to be backwards.)  That would make your example correspond to the byte `0b00100011` or `0x23`.